# Visual Studio 2017 IntelliSense not working correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 Professional on a Windows 10 Pro machine and i have noticed an issue whenever i add a reference to an assembly( or add a nuget package )

For example in my sample app i have added the following to the csproj file:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />`

So when i attempt to write code that utilizes package or reference I've added it Visual Studio doesn't seem recognize it. Even i try to automatically resolve the error by using the command "Alt+Enter or Ctrl+" it doesn't show the correct reference to use in the list.

See below:[image][image]

I have tried  cleaning out the cache and also updated Visual Studio 2017 with the latest patch available.

If i close and open Visual Studio again the issue disappears but its not the ideal solution.

Does anyone have ideas on how i could resolve this issue please?

Comment: I would recommend adding the package references through NuGet instead of adding the package reference to the project file.  I would also try right clicking on the project and select restore nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer, right-click the project under the solution, and click on `Rescan Solution`. This should fix that.